# Write ResultList from DB into a CSV file in Java

Tags: java, export-to-csv

I need to write my `query.getResultList()` into a `.CSV` file.

I call the query over this:

```
    final Query q = em.createNamedQuery("getalljobs");
    final List<Job> joblist = q.getResultList();
```

and the Namequery just do `SELECT * FROM TABLE`, the result of `query.getResultList()` looks like this:

```
[id;name, id;name, ... ]
```

I can't use OpenCSV.

The CSV file needs to have headers.

Comment: So each item in `BerufeList` must be a separate row in target CSV file, right?

Comment: Yes thats right

Comment: There is nothing complex about this.  Simply create a File with .csv extension in Java, then loop over your list, and write to a file using https://howtodoinjava.com/java11/write-string-to-file/  You need to write the Headers first.  Then loop over your List.   Please actually attempt something.

Comment: Can't use it bc I am using java 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like

```java
Query q = em.createNamedQuery("getalljobs");
List<Job> jobList = q.getResultList();
String csvHeader = getHeader();

try (PrintWriter fw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("output.csv"))) {
  fw.println(csvHeader);
  for(String line : jobList){
    fw.println(line);
  }
}
```

Comment: But how do I get or better set the headers by this soulution ?

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**

Write line for line in the file with StringBuidler.append. To this add your comma and a new line after each row.